# JBoss 5.1 Won't Start Using Eclipse Indigo on Windows 8

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am having trouble running JBoss 5.1 through Eclipse Indigo (and JBoss Tools) on my new Windows 8 laptop.  The server starting process hangs indefinitely at the beginning, displaying these two messages: "Starting JBoss 5.1 Runtime Server: (0%)" and "Performing pre-launch check..."  I would appreciate any trouble-shooting tips.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Though I'm on macosx, I was having trouble with this as well. Found out that a rogue jboss process was hanging around in the background.

```
ps aux | grep jboss
```

Note the process id

```
sudo kill -9 <processId>
```

Comment: Just had that on Linux with a suspended (kill -STOP) jetty listening on the same 'target' port as the JBoss I tried to launch.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue in Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7... I didn't feel like I changed anything significant, but I followed these steps and it worked:

1. Originally I installed the JBoss Tools plugin through the Eclipse Marketplace, but I reinstalled it via the "Install New Software" option with this repository URL: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/3_3_Final.html
2. I created a new server, selected JBoss AS 5.1, next to Server Runtime I clicked Add. Chose the directory, and select "web" under configuration.
3. Finish with default settings, do not add any projects yet.
4. This is not related to the server starting, but Eclipse would not deploy anything without doing this: double click the server, open the Deployment tab on the bottom, click "Use JBoss deploy folder" option, save changes.
5. Run the server, hopefully it will successfully start. Then add your projects from the Run As menu, or by right-clicking the server and selecting Add or Remove.

If you happened to find another solution, please share it. I would like to get a better understanding of the problem.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: josh and jacob - if you continue to have this problem on more uptodate versions of JBoss Tools please let us know at https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, just reinstall the server and it is resolved.

Firstly force quite the jboss : esc + command + option and select jboss to force quite;

Then stop and delete the current jboss server;

After that, define a new server by clicking 'new server wizard', and defind the same jboss again.

Then you should be able to start the server.

I don't know why this happens actually, but this works for me. If anyone knows the reason please share your idea.

Thanks.